# GeoServer symbology doesn't show when I use WFS

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, symbology, wfs

I am using GeoServer and OpenLayers 6, and I am trying to use a certain symbology which i defined in GeoServer using SLD.
It works well when I use WMS service, but I couldn't find a way to make it works with WFS service.

I found that in ArcGIS server you can apply a symoboly to a Feature Layer, and make edits on it like in this demo:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to do this using GeoServer and OpenLayers?

Answer (score 1):

WFS sends the raw data to your client, which is responsible for the styling, so this is entirely expected behaviour.

Comment: thank you for your response Ian Turton, i edited my question to express what i really want to do

Comment: You can do this in open layers too, look at other questions on this site

Comment: The problem is that openlayers is very limited in styling. is there any JS library can help doing this ?

Comment: There are some third party utilities which can convert  between SLD and OpenLayers styles https://github.com/geostyler/geostyler  https://github.com/nieuwlandgeo/sldreader

Answer (score 1):

WFS has no support for providing client-side styling information. The [OGC API - Features](https://ogcapi.ogc.org/features/#:%7E:text=OGC%20API%20%2D%20Features%20is%20a,is%20a%20multi%2Dpart%20document.) can have those links, especially when coupled with an `https://github.com/opengeospatial/ogcapi-styles` service. The styling part is still in draft stage though.